# Tensorflow crashes memory google colab

Tags: python, memory-management, tokenize, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on word Embeddings for arabic dialect -like slang of a region- while preprocessing the data:

1. load json
2. extract the lines
3. clean from urls,emojis nd other
4. remove any list has minimum of 2 words
5. create context, target for a window of 2
6. with tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer fit_on_texts

   > 7. **Problem:** create from text to matrix

what i want from step 7 is to make onehot encoding so i can feed it to the network

```
def loadJson(file):
  import json
  lines=[]
  with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
      lines.append(json.loads(line))
  return lines

def extractSentences(lines,language):
  posts=[]
  comments=[]
  for line in lines:
    if line['language']==language:
      posts.append(line['message'])
    for j in line['comments']:
      if j['language']==language:
        comments.append(j['message'])
  return posts, comments

def removeSpecialChar(posts):
  import re
  def remov(p):
    l=re.sub(' {2,}',' ',re.sub('[^ـابتةثجحخدذرزىسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويءآأؤإئّّّّّ:ّّّّّ]',' ',re.sub('َ|ً|ُ|ٌ|ِ|ٍ|ْ','',r""+p.strip())))
    myre = re.compile(u'['
    u'\U0001F300-\U0001F64F'
    u'\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF'
    u'\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF]+', 
    re.UNICODE)
    return myre.sub('',l)
  return list(map(remov,posts))

def delEmpty(posts,size=2):
  while True:
    p=len(posts)
    for j,i in enumerate(posts):
      if len(i.split(' '))<2:
        #print(i.split(' '))
        del posts[j]
    if p-len(posts)==0:
      return 

def contextAndTarget(posts,k=2):
  import numpy as np
  context = []
  target  = []
  for j,i in enumerate(posts):
    ul = [ k for k in i.split(' ') if len(k)>2]
    for handel in range(len(ul)-1):
      for e in range(k):
        if e+handel<len(ul):
          context.append(ul[handel])
          target.append(ul[e+handel])
  X = []
  X.extend(target)
  X.extend(context)
  Y = []
  Y.extend(context)
  Y.extend(target)
  return X,Y
```

after that i apply the processing on the json file nd do all the steps

```
lines=loadJson('data.json')
posts,comments=extractSentences(lines,'ARABIC')
posts=removeSpecialChar(posts)
delEmpty(posts)
X,Y=contextAndTarget(posts)

tokenPosts=preprocessing.text.Tokenizer() 
tokenPosts.fit_on_texts(X)
vocab_size=len(tokenPosts.word_counts)+1

#just right here it crashes nd the RAM increase suddenly 

xLines,yLines=tokenPosts.texts_to_matrix (X),tokenPosts.texts_to_matrix (Y)
```

Comment: How large is your dataset and the corresponding matrix ? I tried to build a huge image with numpy some time ago, but it just crashes on larger matrix than 80.000 x 80.000 because float64 is out of range. If you have a multi dimensional array, you can pass more values in it, maybe 75.000x75.000x75.000 but it consumes tonns of memory. Maybe think about streaming the values, over the RAM, on a local saved Matrix. pyvips for images (example) [link] (https://libvips.github.io/pyvips/vimage.html)

Comment: Alright, so what's the problem?